# Xenial upgrade broke Nova T 500 Tuner

Tags: 16.04, dvb, nova

I upgraded to Xenial and have been having issues with my TV tuner card (Nova T 500 PCI). The card is detected and appears to be loading firmware correctly but mythtv can't see or use it. The strange thing is I managed to get it to work but after I restarted it was broken again. Here is the output from lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2040:9941 Hauppauge WinTV Nova-T-500
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0103 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 0471:0815 Philips (or NXP) eHome Infrared Receiver
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0403:fc60 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c51b Logitech, Inc. V220 Cordless Optical Mouse for Notebooks
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

here is some of my dmesg:

```
    [    8.564253] dvb-usb: found a 'Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T' in warm state.
[    8.564392] dvb-usb: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer.
[    8.565345] DVB: registering new adapter (Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T)
[    8.689172] usb 3-1: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (DiBcom 3000MC/P)...
[    8.697868] MT2060: successfully identified (IF1 = 1220)
[    9.110427] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    9.110872] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    9.110875] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.110881] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.110885] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.110894] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.203072] dvb-usb: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer.
[    9.203200] DVB: registering new adapter (Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T)
[    9.210337] usb 3-1: DVB: registering adapter 1 frontend 0 (DiBcom 3000MC/P)...
[    9.215201] MT2060: successfully identified (IF1 = 1220)
[    9.436080] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
[    9.436097] work still pending
[    9.729251] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    9.735037] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    9.742107] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    9.742505] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    9.832105] Registered IR keymap rc-dib0700-rc5
[    9.832374] input: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:05:02.2/usb3/3-1/rc/rc1/input14
[    9.832801] rc1: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:05:02.2/usb3/3-1/rc/rc1
[    9.833044] dvb-usb: schedule remote query interval to 50 msecs.
[    9.833052] dvb-usb: Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T successfully initialized and connected.
[    9.833246] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_dib0700
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this or debug it?

Answer (score 1):

After 2 weeks of having this issue I've managed to solve this... all I did was remove dvb-dibusb-5.0.0.11.fw from /lib/firmware and now my card is working fine